# Displaying data from a MS SQL Server via wordpress

Tags: php, sql-server, wordpress, asp-classic

I have a very similar situation to the [person in this posting](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/pull-data-from-an-aspnet-database) but I want to make sure we are talking about the same thing.
So, I have a potential client that wants to take his current ASP website and convert most of it to a WordPress website. He spent a lot of money and time developing this back end system which is mainly to keep track of his inventory to some great detail. The purpose for having WordPress site is he wants his employees to be able to easily update blog postings, news, and some images and perhaps galleries.

So we would rebuild his current website using WordPress but the search capabilities of the site would all be pulled from his current MS SQL server (inventory information). I am assuming that there is no plug-in for this as I'm guessing most of this would have to be customized to his current back end system. I probably know just enough about this to confuse you but for those of you who understand what I'm trying to do I would appreciate any input on how to go about accomplishing this or if this is even a viable solution.

So my question here is would this project be worth the time and effort?

Many thanks,
Houston

Comment: I don't see a problem Migrating. You will need custom code and design for the PHP - Mysql interaction and then choose some plugging s for Administering from backend. -- http://wpjournals.com/wordpress/mysql-wordpress-plugins/ -- or create a separate Admin site altogether.

Comment: Thank you Tasos, that is pretty much what I thought. Many thanks.

Comment: You can probably run both Wordpress and the ASP site on the one server. That might be a simple solution.